Hyperref doesn't work with filename including Chinese characters
I want to insert a hyperlink to a local file, but the name of the file includes Chinese characters and \href could not identify it. For example, if I try the following:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:d:/卷一.pdf}{text}
\end{document}

then the filename would be identified as "鍗蜂竴.pdf". But \href actually works well when the URL links to a website including Chinese characters. For example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/代数}{text}
\end{document}

would open the expected page.
So I think the error comes from that my Tex compiler encodes Chinese characters with UTF-8 while my Windows encodes them with GBK. However, for many reasons, I don't want to change the way they encode Chinese characters.
How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to encode Chinese characters with GBK myself and put them into URL? if so, what is the proper format?
Any help would be appreciated.

Which engine do you use for compilation?

I use xelatex for compilation and the package ctex for the typesetting of Chinese characters.

Try if it works if you add \DocumentMetadata{} before \documentclass (this requires a rather current LaTeX). And test first with a file in the current folder and with \href{卷一.pdf}{text}, run is not needed for pdf-files, and absolute pathes add additional complications.

It works! And it seems to work for any relative path. Thank you very much!

fine, be aware that \DocumentMetadata loads the new LaTeX pdfmanagement code and can change the document a bit (e.g. it uses a different hyperref driver, and the link colors will change).

"unicode" file names need some special support in the PDF and legacy hyperref doesn't have it.
But if you use the new PDF management, that you load with \DocumentMetadata the needed key will be added.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{卷一.pdf}{text}

\end{document}

Without the PDF management the action is a simple GoToR to a file name:
  <</S/GoToR/F<e58db7e4b8802e706466>/D[0/Fit]>>

With the PDF management the action points to proper filespec dictionary with an /UF key:
<</S/GoToR/F 4 0 R/D[0/Fit]>>
4 0 obj
<</Type/Filespec/AFRelationship/Unspecified/Subtype/application#2fpdf
  /F<e58db7e4b8802e706466>/UF<feff53774e00002e007000640066>>>
endobj

